# Can't locate DBD/ODBC.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor.)

Tags: perl, odbc, unixodbc

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use DBI;
use warnings;

my $user = "database_user";
my $pass = "database_password";

my $server = "ip";
my $database_name = "db";

my $connectString = "driver={GBase ODBC 8.3 Driver};server=$server;database=$database_name;uid=$user;pwd=$pass";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:$connectString")|| die "Connect failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

When I tried to execute the a.pl script to connect the database, I got the following errors:

```
install_driver(ODBC) failed: Can't locate DBD/ODBC.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 3) line 3.
Perhaps the DBD::ODBC perl module hasn't been fully installed,
or perhaps the capitalisation of 'ODBC' isn't right.
Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge.
```

Then I tried to run `perl -e 'use DBD::ODBC;'` and got same error:

> Can't locate DBD/ODBC.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
> /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
> /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
> /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at -e line 1. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

Can somebody help me to fix it?

Comment: Error clearly says you must install [DBD::ODBC](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC).

Comment: after found DBD-ODBC-1.61 setup package, then I get into the folder and run: perl Makefile.PL, it showed error as followed like this:[root@localhost DBD-ODBC-1.61]# perl Makefile.PL 
Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Makefile.PL line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 21.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the DBD::ODBC module. Use a tool to install the [package from CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC).

You can use the `cpan` executable or preferably `cpanm`:

`$ cpan DBD::ODBC`